# Extrude shapes in tikz 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, 3d

I want to have a shape protruding out of a plane, like the green rectangles here [image: Paint drawing]

So far I have a made a box like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     [x={(1cm,-0.9cm)}, y={(5cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,5cm)}]
 \tikzset{zxplane/.style={canvas is zx plane at y=#1,very thin}}
 \tikzset{yxplane/.style={canvas is yx plane at z=#1,very thin}}

 \begin{scope}[yxplane=-1] %bottom
   \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
   \draw [fill=blue]  (1,0.35) rectangle (0.6,0.8);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[zxplane=-1] %left
       \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[zxplane=1] %right
   \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
      \draw [fill=red] (-0.3, -0.8) rectangle (-0.25,-0.35);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[yxplane=1] %top
       \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
     \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image: tikzsofar]

Is it possible to *extrude* the red rectangle, so that it comes out of the wall (ideal). Alternative option would be to move the blue one up, so that it is at the same height as the red one, but coming out of the wall. Or maybe there is a special setting for this sort of thing?

Sorry if there are mistakes in my code - it's a mish mash of stuff I've found on here and trial and error on my behalf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the value of `yxplane` like

```
\begin{scope}[yxplane=0] %middle
   \draw [fill=red] (1, 0.35) rectangle (-0.3,-1);
 \end{scope}
```

As you change the `z` value the plane move up or down.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
     [x={(1cm,-0.9cm)}, y={(5cm,0cm)}, z={(0cm,5cm)}]
 \tikzset{zxplane/.style={canvas is zx plane at y=#1,very thin}}
 \tikzset{yxplane/.style={canvas is yx plane at z=#1,very thin}}

 \begin{scope}[yxplane=-1] %bottom
   \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
   \draw [fill=blue]  (1,0.35) rectangle (0.6,0.8);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[yxplane=0] %middle
   \draw [fill=red] (1, 0.35) rectangle (-0.3,-1);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[zxplane=-1] %left
       \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[zxplane=1] %right
   \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);

 \end{scope}

 \begin{scope}[yxplane=1] %top
       \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
     \end{scope}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]